# ignores comments when reformatting tcl code indentation

Tags: vim, tcl, indentation

I have try to use this plugin: 
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1717.

But indented code in GVim(for vim it work as I expected) is not looks as I have expect.

For example when I indent this code:

```
if { $cond1 != 1 }  {
    #comment 
    if { $cont2 != 2 }  {
        return
    } else {
    #comment 2
        return
    }
}
```

It's become:

```
if { $cond1 != 1 }  {
#comment 
    if { $cont2 != 2 }  {
        return
    } else {
#comment 2
        return
    }
}
```

Is it possible to ignore comments when indenting the code?

For same reason whenever I type `#` the cursor position changed to the start of the line.

Comment: I would guess that the file type is identified wrongly. This looks as if Vim considers the (Tcl) comments as (C) preprocessor directives. What is the output of `:set filetype`?

Comment: [DevSolar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/60281/devsolar) filetype=tcl

Comment: Hmmm... \me shrugs. You *did* install the [required syntax definition](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1603)? The comments are correctly highlighted, i.e. identified as such?

Comment: [DevSolar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/60281/devsolar)Yes, I install required plugins. The syntax highlighting is OK. Comments are also highlighted properly

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my .vimrc, it may help you here

```
" the following line prevents forcing # to be inserted in column 1
inoremap # X<BS>#
```

If you use `compatible`, then ensure `<` is *not* in `cpoptions`: `cpoptions-=<`